# Why can't I find dart2native in the dart-sdk?

Tags: vim, ctags, dart, flutter

Some existing dart package documentation, such as [dart_ctags](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ctags), call on the flutter/dart developer to employ **dart2native**, but it's no where in current dart or flutter sdks.

Answer (score 0):

[Officially, from dart.dev](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-compile#:%7E:text=The%20dart%20compile%20command%20replaces,that%27s%20especially%20useful%20during%20development.):

> The dart compile command replaces the dart2native, dart2aot, and dart2js commands.

[The Flutter/Dart developer preferring Vim](https://kulkarniamit.github.io/whatwhyhow/howto/use-vim-ctags.html) will find this information valuable given that ctags does not yet support the Dart language, necessitating the use of [the dart-ctags package](https://pub.dev/packages/dart_ctags).

[Dart SDK 2.6 originally introduced dart2native](https://medium.com/dartlang/dart2native-a76c815e6baf#id_token=eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQzMzJhYjU0NWNjMTg5ZGYxMzNlZmRkYjNhNmM0MDJlYmY0ODlhYzIiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.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.LN84aHUHuQ1WYUkRPbyJNzXU53BJom6E-oNL09vpLPCG6fkp211MC2Gq666-Hlqtw0Ia3LpyN96Kqj__0udidekTnENjQyc1lhxGpEeODUwKrJXrgUFVj_r6H9ycd2U1lUXmb5iiLpwifc_wp9iw-uKdldFXMMnbaGxJ3kDS469J7KUVI61DW3UHOkgKVCxUyzcmcjd_T1qVVJcFgvwTbvqmKaLTdTPEKiAnuriXl-itdFgsveN3cVxa2VYXgHoXzLjEweOmjxjlaOnTZtQZqigvhNUmDp4x-6uDGNBN2QCcXaDu2uFHF-7z_PKKRfdyRmPNf6abJ7EAua3DH5O4Mw). Later, [Dart SDK v. 2.8](https://dart.dev/guides/language/evolution#dart-28) introduced the [dart tool, and dart compile,](https://dart.dev/tools/dart-tool) in preparation for null safety. The present null-safe stable Dart SDK version at the time of this writing is 2.16.2 [updated roughly every three months](https://dart.dev/get-dart#release-channels).